# For loop with struct causes crash

Tags: c, struct

[image]So here basically I have two loops which do basically the same thing except they fscanf to different directories.
The second should fscanf to a struct and one causes the program to crash.
Why is that?????
The code which causes the program to crash is the last for loop in the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN 100

int main()
{
    char filename1[MAXLEN];
    char filename2[MAXLEN];
    char filename3[MAXLEN];
    char filename4[MAXLEN];


    char itemname[MAXLEN];
    printf("Enter the input file: ");
    scanf("%s", filename1);
    strcpy(filename3,filename1);
    strcat(filename3,"Output.txt");
    strcpy(filename4,filename1);
    strcat(filename4,"Log.txt");
    strcpy(filename2, filename1);
    strcat(filename2, "Customers.txt");
    strcat(filename1, ".txt");
    printf("%s will be used",filename1);

    FILE *inputfile1 = NULL;
    FILE *inputfile2 = NULL;
    FILE *outputfile = NULL;
    FILE *logfile = NULL;

    inputfile1 = fopen(filename1, "r");
    inputfile2 = fopen(filename2, "r");
    outputfile = fopen(filename3, "w");
    logfile = fopen(filename4, "w"); 

    int numberofitems =0;
    while (fscanf(inputfile1,"%s",itemname)==1){
        numberofitems++;
    }
    rewind(inputfile1);
    numberofitems /= 4;

    struct storestock{ 
    char itemnames[numberofitems][MAXLEN];
    int isdecimal[numberofitems];
    double stock[numberofitems];
    double price[numberofitems];
    };

    typedef struct storestock store;

    store inventory;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < numberofitems; i++)
    {
    fscanf(inputfile1,"%s %d %lf %lf",inventory.itemnames[i],&(inventory.isdecimal[i]),
    &(inventory.stock[i]),&(inventory.price[i]));
    printf("\n %dst item %s %d %lf %lf", i+1,inventory.itemnames[i],inventory.isdecimal[i]
    ,inventory.stock[i],inventory.price[i] );
    }

    struct customers{
        char customername[MAXLEN];
        char wanteditems[10][MAXLEN];
        double amountwanted[10];
    };


    int j,k,l;
    int numberofcustomers = 0;
    int itemnumber=0;
    double itemamount;
    char string[MAXLEN];
    for (j=0;j<100;j++){
        if (fscanf(inputfile2,"%s %lf", string,&itemamount)==1){
            numberofcustomers++;
            printf("\n%s",string);
    }}
    printf("%d", numberofcustomers);

    struct customers mycustomers[numberofcustomers];
    rewind(inputfile2);

    **for (k=0;k<100;k++){
        if (fscanf(inputfile2,"%s %lf", mycustomers[k].customername,&itemamount)==1){
            printf("\n%s", mycustomers[k].customername);}
            }**
    getch();
    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: Try `for(k = 0; k < numberofcustomers; k++)`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Didn't work Cool Guy

Comment: What does the `printf("%d", numberofcustomers);` show? Is it zero? Because the line `numberofcustomers++` is inside an `if` block that has a conditional that looks suspiciously wrong, `if (fscanf(inputfile2,"%s %lf", string,&itemamount)==1)`. That `fscanf` reads **two** inputs but then checks that only **one** was read. So assuming the input file is well formed it means that conditional will never be true and hence `numberofcustomers` will be zero.

Comment: @CoolGuy I am not sure if that works. `numberofcustomers` is determined at run-time from a file. I thought C determines the size at compile-time, not run-time.

Comment: Number of customers is 3

Comment: I just used it to check whether the scanning process is being done properly

Comment: I used mycustomers[k] because I have an array of structs and I want to fscanf a string  and assign it to the customername of the first struct then scan another string and fscanf it to the customername of the 2nd struct and so on

Comment: @Elyasin I think you need to read up on [VLAs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Comment: @ AbdulwahabHajar Please post a [mcve] as @martin has commented. Also, show the contents of the file, your input, expected output and current output. Please try to shorten the code.

Answer (score 1):

This code is illegal:

```
struct storestock{ 
    char itemnames[numberofitems][MAXLEN];
```

The dimensions of an array in a struct must be constant expressions (except for *flexible array member*, which this isn't).

You need to redesign your code to not do this. It's hard to see how your compiler would have gotten past this line.

A better approach would be for `struct storestock` to actually have just one of each item, and then you have an array of such structs (which *can* have the size `numberofitems`). Similar to what you did with `struct customers`.

---

The first part of the code, before the `FILE *` lines, performs a lot of writing to buffers with no size checking .This may cause a buffer overflow leading to unpredictable behaviour. It would be good to replace all of this guff with length-checked `scanf` and then use `snprintf` instead of `strcpy` and `strcat`.